# Subquery output

Tags: sql, subquery

Hi I'm still learning the ins and outs of SQL subqueries, and I'm wondering if anyone can show me the table column headers that will result from the following query. Trying to figure out and visualize how subqueries work. Thanks!

```
SELECT
    t2.id,
    t2.type,
    t2.start AS exit,
    t2.last,
    t2.last_time AS entrnc,
    CASE WHEN res.fac IN ('Resort1', 'Resort2', 'Resort3','Resort4',
            ) THEN 'new_resort'
                        WHEN res.fac IS NULL THEN 'not_new_res'
                        ELSE 'other_resort' END AS gst
FROM
    (SELECT
        id,
        start,
        type,
        Min(start) Over (PARTITION BY id, Cast(start AS DATE) ORDER BY start ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS last_time,
        Min(type) Over (PARTITION BY id, Cast(start AS DATE) ORDER BY start ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS last
        QUALIFY ( Min(type) Over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) LIKE '%Entrance%')
    FROM
        (SELECT
            f1.*
        FROM foo f1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
                    id
                FROM foo
                WHERE type = 'Exit'
                ) AS f2
        ON f1.id = f2.id
        ) t1
    ) t2
LEFT JOIN reservations res ON res.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.type = 'Exit'
    AND t2.last LIKE '%Entrance%'
```

Comment: Sorry the formatting didn't go through! Let me know if it's too frustrating to understand unformatted.

Comment: Add a tag of your sql language

Comment: Why do many different types of quote characters?

Comment: The way you have it, it will not even compile. There are errors - one of them is an extra comma after the 'Resort4' item...To find out what the result set from a subquery looks like, you can just execute that one subquery you are interested in.

Comment: You are asking what the result of your query would be.  Have to tried running it to see what output you get?

Comment: Ya sorry. It's early here. My brain wasn't thinking haha

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Subqueries** works like "subsets" of information. It's very useful when you want to "pre-arrange" data in a specific way, or to prepare/filter data for "join".

If it's true that you are very  new to SQL and Subselects you should try to understand simpler cases.

A very good way to understand that is to study a little bit of "[Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory)". Here goes a very simple example to demonstrate how subqueries work:

Imagine 2 tables:

```
product_description
  product_code integer,
  product_description varchar(50)

product_types
  product_code integer,
  prodcut_type varchar(50)

select
   t1.product_description,
   t2.product_type
from
   (
      select product_code, product_description from product_descriptions
   ) t1
   inner join
   (
      select product_code, product_type from product_types
   ) t2
on 
   t1.product_code = t2.product_code
```

This is not very much a "real world" example, because this query does the same as:

```
select
       t1.product_description,
       t2.product_type
    from
       product_descriptions t1
       inner join
       product_types t2
    on 
       t1.product_code = t2.product_code
```

But it's actually pretty good to understand subqueries behaviour. Also the best way to "debug" queries with big and complex subselects, is to go from inside out, and analyzing each subset.

You can work with filter, agregations and ranks, as in your example.

A thing to keep in mind is about query performance. Even though it's a very useful resource, you must plan very carefully your query when working with high volumes of data.

Hope that's useful somehow.

Regards